# Anyone Try Running Rails 2.2 (or Edge) under Ruby 1.9.1 RC1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

Ruby 1.9.1 RC1 was released today so I quickly moved to install it (a test version of course using a suffix of 19). I install Rails and Rack for the 1.9 RubyGems and then create a new Rails site using edge... when I execute:

```
ruby19 ./script/server
```

I watch as the processor usage goes up to 99.8 and the terminal just sits there. Trying to run Rails 2.2 using 1.9.1RC1 gives all sorts of fail on the inflector. I was under the impression that Rails 2.2 was 1.9.1 compatible. Is anyone successfully testing Rails under Ruby 1.9.1 or are you seeing similar errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing for me.

I'm running the latest edge rails under webrik and just see the blank screen and no response to Ctrl-C. Rails 2.2 isn't working at all.

Also, I've tried run edge under thin (with eventmachine from github fixed to build on ruby 1.9.1, except one broken ruby test - I've just added empty one with 'assert true').

After that, both webrick and thin crashes immediately with:

$ /usr/local/bin/ruby script/server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.3/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.1 (2008-12-30 patchlevel-0 revision 21203) [i386-darwin9.6.0]

So, I guess, we all need calm down now. There still much work to actually run our rails apps under 1.9.1. Many gems are still at the early stages of bringing compatibility with 1.9.1

Actually, rails 2.2 is not fully compatible with ruby 1.9.1, just a basic compatibility, according to rails core team :)

Full compatibility claimed in upcoming rails 2.3.

Comment: But you would think that "basic compatibility" means "it will start" - ;)

Answer (score 1):

I [have written a guide on using Rails edge (near enough to 2.3) and Ruby 1.9.1](http://frozenplague.net/2009/01/ruby-191-rubygems-rails/). mysql, postgres and a few other gems like hpricot, thin and mongrel don't work, but the application does work.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2.2.2 is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.1rc1 when processing characters and strings on ActiveSupport. Rails uses multibyte to support unicode char-set, in other hand Ruby 1.9.1 uses built-in unicode support. Supported versions is 1.8.5 to 1.8.7.